# How to update a ref in a Vue app from external code?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently working on code similar to the following, trying to create a simple countdown timer:

```
const {createApp, ref} = Vue

const app = createApp({
    setup(_, { expose }) {
        const timer = ref("00:00")
        return {
            timer
        }
    }
})

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    app.mount('#app')

    let remaining = 60 * 12
    setInterval(()=>{
        console.log("interval")
        if (remaining <= 0) return;
        remaining--
        const minutes = remaining/60
        const seconds = remaining % 60
        app.timer = `${Math.trunc(minutes).toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, "0")}`
    }, 1000);
})
```

The issue I'm having is that I can't get the app to update the printed value at all (it works if I move the increment code to within setup, but I want to avoid that). I'm feeling a bit lost about the cleanest way to do this. I'm using Vue within an electron app, and I want to eventually hook up the vue code to messages passed from the main process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app` is application object and not root component instance, it plays the same role as `Vue` in Vue 2.

It should be:

```
const instance = app.mount('#app')
...
instance.timer = ...
```

Unless Vue application is third-party code that cannot be modified, it's a good practice to move all relevant logic (`setInterval`, etc) inside the application and expose public methods to interact with the page.

Comment: I completely missed that! Thanks. I've marked it as the correct answer. I understand encapsulating the internal logic. I'm just learning about how the framework works at the moment.